# Imagemagick caption - output chosen font size

Tags: imagemagick

I am using the caption function within an imagemagick batch file to automatically wrap and best fit like this...

```
magick -background lightblue -fill blue -size 1000x500 caption:"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent porttitor magna sed finibus vestibulum. Phasellus non leo vestibulum, porta justo non, venenatis quam. Morbi risus lacus, accumsan nec pellentesque eget, molestie nec arcu. Nunc tincidunt nulla non enim vulputate mattis. " output.jpg
```

This is working correctly but I would like to use the chosen font size elsewhere in my script.  Is there a way to get imagemagick to output the settings it chose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated Answer**

Oooh, I learned something new:

```
magick -print "%[caption:pointsize]" ....
```

will tell you the answer directly!

**Original Answer**

You can use:

```
magick -debug annotate ... output.jpg 2>&1 | grep -E "pointsize|Metrics:"
```

and look at the last line with `pointsize` to see it chose `54.75`. I am not sure if there is an easier way though.

Maybe more succinctly like this:

```
magick -debug annotate ... output.jpg 2>&1 | grep "pointsize" | tail -1
Font /Library/Fonts/Arial.ttf; font-encoding none; text-encoding none; pointsize 54.75
```